# Landing pages: 301 or not?

Tags: seo, http-status-code-301

We have a bunch of landingpages: http://ourdomain/landingpage. Each landingpage is unique in terms of title, texts, metatags, ... We mostly use these landingpages for adwords traffic, but also for offsite SEO links and banner campaigns.

Today when a user enters a landingpage, a cookie (session variable) is set and then the user is 301 redirected to http://ourdomain where the "landingpage" is generated.

My question is if this is the best way in terms of SEO? Should I skip the 301 and build PR for each landingpage or build PR for my domain?

Note that each landingpage has their own set of keywords (different product categories).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each landing page can be somewhat associated to an existing page, I would suggest to skip the redirect and go with a [canonical link tag](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html).